# Get values from php array using a key value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array similar to this below. I need to find a way to extract values by using a key/value pair for instance by using `'parent_id' => 3`. I want to get all values for said `array ( id = 2, label = Content Creation, link_url = '', parent_id = 3 )`.

I've tried using `array_intersect()` without any success.

Thank You for your assistance.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [label] => Web Development [link_url] => [parent_id] => 1 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [label] => Content Creation [link_url] => [parent_id] => 3 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [label] => PHP Jobs [link_url] => /simple_link.php [parent_id] => 1 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [label] => OSCommerce projects [link_url] => /another_link.php [parent_id] => 4 )
)
```

Comment: the manual page for array_search has some functions that would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thik you can loop in your array and match your desidered `parent_id` with an if condition

```
foreach($array as $data)
{
    if($data['parent_id'] == '3')
    {
        echo $data['id'] . ' ' . $data['label'] . ' ' . $data['link_url'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use array_filter for these sort of problems

```
$matching_results = array_filter($data, function($item) {
   return ($item['parent_id'] == 3);
});
```

It will cycle through the data and $matching_results will be an array of each $item that returns true

Comment: Yes, this works as well, think it depends on final application, THX